# Converting a field to lower case and merging data in an sqlite database

Tags: sqlite

I need to merge some randomly uppercased data that has been collected in an SQLite table `key_val`, such that `key` is always lowercase and no `val`s are lost. There is a unique compound index on `key,val`.

The initial data looks like this:

```
key|val
abc|1
abc|5
aBc|1
aBc|5
aBc|3
aBc|2
AbC|1
abC|3
```

The result after the merge would be

```
key|val
abc|1
abc|2
abc|3
abc|5
```

In my programmer brain, I would

```
for each `key` with upper case letters; 
  if a lower cased `key` is found with the same value
    then delete `key`
    else update `key` to lower case
```

Re implementing the loop has a sub query for each row found with upper case letters, to check if the `val` already exists as a lower case `key`

If it does, I can delete the cased `key`.

From there I can `UPDATE key = lower(key)` as the "duplicates" have been removed.

The first cut of the programming method of finding the dupes is:

```
SELECT * FROM key_val as parent 
WHERE parent.key != lower(parent.key) 
 AND 0 < (
           SELECT count(s.val) FROM key_val as s
           WHERE s.key = lower(parent.key) AND s.val = parent.val
         )
ORDER BY parent.key DESC;
```

I'm assuming there's a better way to do this in SQLite? The `ON CONFLICT` functionality seems to me like it should be able to handle the dupe deletion on `UPDATE` but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First delete all the duplicates:

```
DELETE FROM key_val AS k1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM key_val AS k2 
  WHERE LOWER(k2.key) = LOWER(k1.key) AND k2.val = k1.val AND k2.rowid < k1.rowid 
);
```

by keeping only 1 combination of `key` and `val` with the min `rowid`.
It is not important if you kept the key with all lower chars or not, because the 2nd step is to update the table:

```
UPDATE key_val
SET key = LOWER(key);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=451a08152faa17a568848f76474777e1).

Answer (score 1):

Honestly it might just be easier to create a new table and then insert into it.  As it seems you really just want a distinct select here, use:

```sql
INSERT INTO kev_val_new ("key", val)
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER("key"), val
FROM key_val;
```

Once you have populated the new table, you may drop the old one, and then rename the new one to the previous name:

```sql
DROP TABLE key_val;
ALTER TABLE key_val_new RENAME TO key_val;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Tim that it would be easire to re-create table using simple *select distict lower()*.. statement, but that's not always easy if table has dependant objects (indexes, triggers, views). In this case this can be done as sequence of two steps:

insert lowered keys which are not still there:

```
insert into t
select distinct lower(tr.key) as key, tr.val 
from t as tr
left join t as ts on ts.key = lower(tr.key) and ts.val = tr.val
where ts.key is null;
```

now when we have all lowered keys - remove other keys:

```
delete from t where key <> lower(key);
```

See fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/84db50/11
However this method assumes that key is always populated (otherwise it would be a strange key)

If vals can be null then "ts.val = tr.val" should be replaced with more complex stuff like ifnull(ts.val, -1) = ifnull(tr.val, -1) where -1 is some unused value (can be different). If we can't assume any unused value like -1 then it should be more complex check for null / not null cases.